# How to replace componentswillreceive props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react and other front-end technologies. I was following along a coding tutorial but it has a deprecated function "componentWillReceiveProps()".

I have googled the problem, tried to implement the new functions getDerivedStateFromProps and componentDidUpdate but could not fix the issue due to incorrect usage.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import classnames from "classnames";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // If logged in and user navigates to Login page, should redirect them to dashboard
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();


    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }} className="row">
          <div className="col s8 offset-s2">
            <Link to="/" className="btn-flat waves-effect">
              <i className="material-icons left">keyboard_backspace</i> Back to
              home
            </Link>
            <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
              <h4>
                <b>Login</b> below
              </h4>
              <p className="grey-text text-darken-1">
                Don't have an account? <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
              </p>
            </div>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.email}
                  error={errors.email}
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.email || errors.emailnotfound
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <span className="red-text">
                  {errors.email}
                  {errors.emailnotfound}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  error={errors.password}
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.password || errors.passwordincorrect
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <span className="red-text">
                  {errors.password}
                  {errors.passwordincorrect}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
                <button
                  style={{
                    width: "150px",
                    borderRadius: "3px",
                    letterSpacing: "1.5px",
                    marginTop: "1rem"
                  }}
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3"
                >
                  Login
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loginUser }
)(Login);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have 2 options here.**

1. Rename the method. Which will work till **`React 17.x`**.

To rename the method, you can do this,

```
cd your_project
npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles
```

For more information read [this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/08/react-v16.9.0.html).

2. Another way is using `componentDidUpdate` method.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(prevProps.auth.isAuthenticated !== this.props.auth.isAuthenticated){
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
   }

   if (prevProps.errors !== this.props.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: this.props.errors
      });
    }
}
```

Read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) to know more about when to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` and when to use `componentDidUpdate`.

**Note:** As you are working with `history` object, you need to wrap your component using [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) HOC. Something like this,

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loginUser }
)(Login));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `componentWillReceiveProps` you provided works with the component you have (it has the correct props, etc), then the following should replace it using `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  // this is shorthand for if true (?), then do this action, else (:) do this action
  return props.errors ? { errors: props.errors } : null
}
```

`getDerivedStateFromProps` must be a static method. It takes current `props` as its first argument and current `state` as the second argument. It must `return` a modified object state or `null` (null escapes state updates). It's important to note that static methods won't have access to `this`.

For side effects, like history updates, you should utilize `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;

  if (prevProps.auth.isAuthenticated !== isAuthenticated) {
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
  }
}
```